# Question migration does not maintain accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

Question [10575](https://superuser.com/questions/10575/turning-off-the-cmd-window-beep-sound) was just migrated to SU from SO but the "accepted answer" checkbox was not. Does this mean the asking user needs to mark the answer as accepted again?

Comment: While this was older, I'm voting this as a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15275/migrated-questions-losing-their-accepted-answers), as that one actually has an explanation.

Comment: @Grace: Jeff just close voted the other one as a dupe of this. Voting to reopen the other one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer will now persist when it is migrated.