# Migrated questions losing their accepted answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question migration does not maintain accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/question-migration-does-not-maintain-accepted-answer)

I'm not referring to the fact that migrated questions will appear to lose their answers when they get migrated to a different site, but when they actually *do* get migrated, the answers keep their upvotes, downvotes, and comments, but if an answer was accepted pre-migration, it will no longer be considered accepted.

Is this how its suppose to work? If it is, why would a question be considered unresolved just because it moved sites?

(I considered the possibility that the OP might have unmarked it as accepted before it got migrated, but that doesn't seem likely.)

Comment: Does status by design mean they're suppose to lose their accepted status (if so, why?) or does it mean that I'm just crazy and wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had some questions migrated from SO and haven't followed up on them since; why do they show up as having no accepted answer? It makes no kind of sense.

Because the user whose answer you are "accepting" may not exist on the target site at the time of migration.

Votes is a close enough proxy to this, and you can accept answers on the target site all day long once you associate your account and own the migrated question.

In short, there are severe technical issues involved doing this "automatically", and the workaround is trivial (associate, own the question, and accept an answer).

Comment: “while this might be [by-design] it is bad design.” https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34176/163139

Answer (score 10):

I just added the last vote to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499331/do-stackoverflow-questions-represent-the-current-state-of-the-programming-industr?noredirect=1

that saw it migrated over to meta:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34154/do-stackoverflow-questions-represent-the-current-state-of-the-programming-industr

Before the move, Jon Skeet's answer was the accepted one, and now it isn't. So while this might be [by-design] it is bad design.

Comment: @ChrisF, I agree. I'm guessing the design decision was that when a question is moved to a more suitable site then not having an accepted answer would encourage more answers by more knowledgeable users. That's likely true, but if the problem was already solved by someone, I think that should still be recognized.

Answer (score 5):

Acceptance status should not go away because of migration.

Edit:  I can see where my statement was somewhat vague, I meant that the behavior shouldn't be allowed to happen, but I believe the poster that it probably is happening.

Comment: I see. Good to know I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same thing happen and I also don't understand why this is "by design". If the asker has accepted an answer then how does migrating to another site change that?