# Is there a way to appeal "status-bydesign" decisions?

Tags: discussion, appeal

I've run into a few cases in which bug reports were closed as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) where I really feel that the design process should be rethought.

Is there a way to say, *I understand you think this is not a bug but I think you should reconsider*? After all Jeff keeps saying he was against meta till he saw the light; how can we shine the light in his eyes?

I'm guessing that removing the tag is inappropriate...

A prime example of this is [Migrated questions lose their accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15275/migrated-questions-losing-their-accepted-answers). I had some questions migrated from SO and haven't followed up on them since; why do they show up as having no accepted answer? It makes no kind of sense.

Comment: I don't even think you *can* remove the tag.

Comment: Moderator-only tags can't be added or removed by anyone except moderators. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-are-the-rules-different-on-meta/47640#47640

Comment: Your feature request IS the appeal of the "status-by-design"

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow/37832#37832

Answer (score 10):

I despise the idea of using terms like `status-by-design` and `status-declined` in front of the user (you know, US!). This really flies in the face of everything that good customer service is about. Could you imagine sending food back at a restaurant and having the chef come out and say "it's supposed to taste like that, just eat it."

While there is no actual appeals process, I never hesitate to vote/answer/comment on declined feature requests. Perhaps if enough momentum builds Jeff will reconsider.

Comment: +1 *cough* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes *cough*

Comment: Who is the better chef, the one saying "this is the way I cook, if you don't like it, get lost", or the one lying in your face about how valuable your feedback is and that it will most certainly be taken into consideration, while absolutely zero will ever happen? I'd much rather have the honest feedback.

Comment: @Pekka - only one of those chefs will remain in business.

Comment: @Jon B I don't mean the chef saying literally "get lost." There are friendly ways to do that. I'm just saying, to me, feedback on feature requests *is* part of running a transparent, user-oriented community. Would you really prefer inaction (or "we'll think about it") to an honest `status-declined` when in fact it has internally been declined?

Comment: @Pekka - it doesn't have to be `status-maybe` or `status-thank-you-your-call-is-important-to-us`. My point is that simply stamping `status-declined` on something is like saying `status-bite-me`. Especially on issues like the one Jon Seigel linked to, where there is overwhelming community support. It would be nice if there was a way the SO team could respond more diplomatically to these.

Comment: @Jon B now *that* I second completely. A bit more explaining why something gets declined, and a display of some appreciation (or consideration) for the energy put into all these feature requests would do well, absolutely. I thought you meant the act of declining requests in itself.

Comment: I doubt voting up closed (or _resolved_) questions has any affect, my guess is they only look at questions with no resolution tags.

Comment: "Innovation is not about saying yes to everything. It's about saying NO to all but the most crucial features" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/just-say-no.html

Comment: I also think the type of users who have the self esteem to handle someone saying no to them like an adult, are HEALTHIER users. They understand (constructive) criticism and are not internalizing every request they make. Those users who are driven away by the occasional "no" are not the kind of users you want anyway.

Comment: @Jeff - Are we talking about software development and users, or business and customers? I'm not advocating saying "yes" to everything, I'm suggesting a more customer service-like attitude. Aside from the peer review nature of SO, people are not here to receive constructive criticism from you. You are receiving constructive criticism from US. A little grace and humility would be appropriate.

Comment: @jon There are no "customers"! There are only peer community members. You can say no to me, I can say no to you. Or we can work together.

Comment: @Jeff - I'm disappointed and surprised to hear that that's your attitude about your users. As much as I would love to have a more in depth discussion about the business of running a site like this, this isn't the right place so I'll just stop here.

Answer (score 5):

You can "appeal" by opening a feature request to change the existing design.

Comment: But such a request has already been closed, won't the new one be closed as duplicate the minute it's opened?

Comment: @Motti: Bug reports are closed as by-design. A feature request is not the same as a bug report. Now if a feature request is status-declined, that's different. In that case, there's no real appeal possible.

Answer (score 1):

## No

<sub>I mean, you can bring the topic up here on Meta, but Jeff is unlikely to change his mind unless you bring a pretty compelling case.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

> I had some questions migrated from SO and haven't followed up on them since; why do they show up as having no accepted answer? It makes no kind of sense.

Ok, so why don't you associate your account, retain ownership of the questions, and accept an answer?

What's stopping *you* from fixing it?

Comment: -1 because you're answering the question he referenced, not the question he was asking (which involved appealing `status-declined`).

Comment: @jonb I actually answered both.. go check!

Comment: I did associate my account, however I don't frequent meta very much (my guess is that I'm in the majority) and didn't follow up on my migrated answers (which I didn't know where migrated). 

I think the data which would tell us if this "by design" feature is the correct behaviour would be to look at the migrated questions (which had accepted answers) and see how many of them 1) Have no accepted answer 2) Have the same accepted answer as they had in the original site 3) Have an accepted answer different from the original site.

If #3 outweighs the other two then it's the correct decision.