# How do migrations handle favorited questions?

Tags: support, migration, bookmarks

Didn't find any talk of this so my curiosity got the best of me.

How do migrations handle favorited questions? My guess would be the favorite link would stay on the original site to the closed migrated question and I would assume any favorite marks would be reset on the site migrated to.

This isn't really that important, but just curious what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I never thought of this ...

I'm going to guess that nothing happens at all. That if you favorited the pre-migration question, that favorite stays and nothing happens on the target site.

1. Your user account may not exist on the target site.
2. A closed post is still present in the system.

We'll run two tests:

**What happens when you favorite a question and it gets migrated later?**

We collectively ran the experiment of favoriting a [question pre-migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521915/is-there-a-way-to-delete-truncate-a-file-while-a-process-is-writing-to-it), and then got it [migrated](https://serverfault.com/questions/86092/is-there-a-way-to-delete-truncate-a-file-while-a-process-is-writing-to-it). (Don't worry, it was a correct and valid migration.)

The results were as I'd expected: My favorite remained on SO, and was not migrated to SF. So there you have it, favoriting has no effect on a pre-migration question.

**Can you favorite a question which has been migrated?**

This is actually an after-the-fact test -- can you favorite a [closed-and-migrated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749566/how-to-migrate-a-bare-metal-linux-installation-to-a-virtual-machine-closed)?

Yes, you can. And it is a favorite on the originating site. It is not favorited on the target site. This makes sense to me, based on the logic above. (Note: I have unfavorited it.)

Comment: Whee, we're on an adventure!

Comment: We're up to 3 close votes ... (I almost feel bad, but the question *does* legitimately belong on SF.)

Comment: Migrated - NO MERCY!

Comment: Maybe I'm going crazy here, but didn't that question (the first one we were asked to close) have an accepted answer pre-migration?

Comment: @Brandon: Here ya go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/question-migration-does-not-maintain-accepted-answer

Comment: @Troggy, I see, thanks for the link. I asked a similar question back in August (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15275/migrated-questions-losing-their-accepted-answers) but was left confused by the only answer I got and the "status-by-design" tag Jeff left.

Comment: Excellent investigation work. Have a cigar on me.