# Voting issues for migrated questions

Tags: bug, voting, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question migration does not maintain accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/question-migration-does-not-maintain-accepted-answer)

Today I re-visited my famous ["What should a web developer know before building a public web site?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site) question because someone posted another answer, and I noticed two issues resulting from the migration to programmers.stackexchange:

1. I had to re-select the accepted answer
2. I was able to upvote this answer for a second time

I suspect these are really the same bug, because I understand from the data dump that accepted answers are just a special kind of vote; somewhere in the migration process, it's not keeping good track of my original votes.  I'm not sure I had an account yet a programmers.stackexchange at the time this was first migrated.

Answer (score 2):

The [double voting issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user) has been discussed here and is currently marked Status-By-Design.

The [migration does not maintain selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/question-migration-does-not-maintain-accepted-answer) should be fixed, Status-Completed.

Perhaps this is just because it was an old post?